# Protect whole column of google sheet using app script automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to protect the whole column every day in order using the app script.
For Example:
On day 1: Protect col A,
On day 2: Protect col B... etc

Comment: for protecting a range see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993561
 -  for getting the day out of a date see Date's method getDay() - and for getting an entire column by the number, use a combination of getRange and getMaxRows

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: What happens when it reaches the last column? It goes back to A? Consider explaining what you tried, including whatever code you're currently working on.